# How to get an observable's value without triggering new emit

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

How can I get the value of an observable when it emits without triggering a new emit? I want to get the value of an observable in an ngClass tag.

I tried using pipe tap to get values as they come through the switchMap but it's not getting logging the value. Then I can use `trueIfDefinitionsLength` for the ngClass condition.

```
this.definitions$.pipe(
  tap(value => console.log('timer result =', value))
)
```

The observable subscribed with | async

Template:

```
<input [ngClass]="{'input-has-results': trueIfDefinitionsLength > 0}"
       [formControl]="searchInput">

<ng-container *ngIf="definitions$ | async as definitions">
  <div class="format-options" *ngIf="definitions.length > 0">
    <div *ngFor="let definition of definitions" class="search-result">
      <div>{{definition.name}}</div>
      <div>{{definition.description}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Component

```
this.definitions$ = this.searchInput.valueChanges
                        .pipe(
                            tap(value => console.log('input')),
                            //startWith(''),
                            debounceTime(500),
                            //distinctUntilChanged(),
                            switchMap(value => this.definitionService.searchTerm(value))
                        );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `BehaviorSubject` instead. It has a method `getValue()` to fetch the current value without emitting a new one.

Comment: what about Subject?

Comment: It doesn't have a method to get the current value.

Comment: yes, i deleted the comment.. is it possible to get values in the component code in the result of switchMap?

Comment: the latest/current value of definition$

Comment: Couldn't you just get the value of the `BehaviorSubject` and do an if-else check to determine what you need to do once you get the desired value? Would that work for you?

Comment: is BehaviorSubject for sharing the state/values whenever the stream emits and Observables like a private stream? I'm confused why I couldn't do this with an Observable.

Comment: Two things here 1. Observables and Subjects are not the same - with a Subject you can decide when to emit a value and this value is the same across all *subscribers*. This isn't the case with an observable. 2. A subject can't have an initial value, that's where a BehaviourSubject kicks in.

Comment: BehaviorSubject is what I'm looking for too I'll implement that

Answer (score 1):

`ReplaySubject` might also come handy in this situation. It caches n last `next`'s and then republishes them for each new subscriber that haven't seen those yet.

Comment: why not have Subject and ReplaySubject's functions in Observables?

Comment: @doe, because you should keep things simple and responsible for one clear task. Observable is something that you can be observed. That's it. Observer is something that can observe. Subject is Observable and Observer at the same time.